# Meaning of même

Tags: sens, adverbes

I am having a difficulty understanding the meaning of this sentense.

> En France, tout le monde parle français, même les enfants.

In particular, what does

> même les enfants

mean ?

My attempt at translation..

> In France everyone speaks French, just like children. ..Or same as children.

Please correct me.

Comment: A [dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/m%C3%AAme) would have answered your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case **même** is an emphasizer. It means even.

> In France everyone speaks French, even the children.

Answer (score 6):

*Même* also means *even* not only *same*

It has an emphatic role in this case to stress that the children speak it as well!

Example:

> Même avec des sacs gonflables perfectionnés...

*Even with advanced airbags...*  You may often see that in cars.

In this example it translates to:

> In France, everyone speaks French, even the children.

Answer (score 3):

We use it as adjective to identify something is identical to an other OR is is being use in an expressive manner to put emphasis on something.

The best trick I can give you the recognize it is when, même, is not used as a comparative, it often being use like that : ...même qu'il a dit ça. ... lui-même.

It being use almost the same as even in english. For example

> Oh!, I can't beleive it !! even him did that ?
>
> Oh, Je peux y croire!! Même lui a fait ça ?

Or sometimes it will be use like you would say himself

> This as been written by Mi4_Slayer himself.
>
> Ceci a été écrit par Mi4_Slayer lui-même.

Even the French is my native language, I am no expert in the very depth of it's grammar, but I hope this help you to understand more of it use in a sentence.

Also I am from Quebec and we tend to multipurpose more the word même more than our cousins from Europe. But I think it will be enough to get the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Or "In France everyone speaks French, including children."

Answer (score 1):

Possible meanings:
If used before an article: even
If used before a noun: same
If used after a noun: very

Comment: Bad formatting and some incorrect information there.